# Chrome Extension: Change background Color on pageLoad

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to change the background color of web page onLoad.
But, the script is not being executed
Here is my code.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Page Redder",
  "description": "Make the current page red",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Make this page red"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
if (changeInfo.status == 'complete')
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file:"code.js"});
});

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="green"'
});
});
```

code.js

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"
```

It is working when I click on the Extension Icon. But, `code.js` is not being executed.

Comment: Try to change permission from `activeTab` to `tabs` (see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use content scripts.  They are much simpler than doing it directly from the background.

content scripts are automatically inserted into your new loaded tab if you use the match `"matches": ["<all_urls>"]`

documentation: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts